# How to disable generic @page rule in VF page rendered as PDF?

Tags: visualforce, pdf, renderas, style

I have following two requirements:

(1) Several single Visualforce pages rendered as PDF with a running header/footer as well as each VF page having a different “padding-top” value of it’s content, i.e. spacing between header and content area, please see code for testPage1 and testPage2 below

(2) One single VF page rendered as PDF which includes all the single VF pages described in (1), please see code for testDoc below

Issue:
As the single VF pages each have different spacing between header and content, I assume having to use named @page rules. The header, footer and content get displayed as intended following this approach, however a single blank page before the actual header, footer and content is inserted. I assume it is because the generic @page rule gets applied (blank first page) as I am using only the named @page class for  tags in each single page. When applying `body { page: page1; }` the blank page is not shown in the single page but in the encompassing page.

Question:
I have scanned several documentation on W3 paged media, however can not find an attribute or tag to be set in order to hide the single first page. Would there be a solution or alternative approach?

````
<!-- testPage1 -->
<apex:page renderAs="advanced_pdf" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css" media="print">
   @page page1 {
    background-color: green;
    padding-top: 200px;
   @top-center {
    vertical-align: top;
    content: element(header);
   }   
   @bottom-center {
    content: element(footer);
   }
   position: absolute;
    top: 0;
   }
   div.Page1Header {
    page: page1;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: running(header);
   }     
   div.Page1Footer {
    page: page1;
    position: running(footer);
   }        
   div.Page1Content { 
    page: page1;
   }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="Page1Header">
    Header ("testPage1")
   </div>
   <div class="Page1Footer">
    Footer ("testPage1")
   </div>
   <div class="Page1Content">
    Content ("testPage1")        *<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>
*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>*<br/>
   </div>
</body>   
</html>
</apex:page>


<!-- testPage2 -->
<apex:page renderAs="advanced_pdf" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
<head>
  <style type="text/css" media="print">
   @page page2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    @top-center {
     vertical-align: top;
     content: element(header);
    }
    @bottom-center {
     content: element(footer);
    }
   }     
   div.Page2Header {
    page: page2;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: running(header);
   }     
   div.Page2Footer {
    page: page2;
    position: running(footer);
   }        
   div.Page2Content {                    
    page: page2;
   }
   </style>
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="Page2Header">
     Header ("testPage2")
    </div>
    <div class="Page2Footer">
     Footer ("testPage2")
    </div>
    <div class="Page2Content">
     Content ("testPage2")    
    </div>
</body>   
</apex:page>



<!-- testDoc -->
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
<html>
<head>
  <style>
   @page {
    display:none;
   }
   @page page1 {
    background-color: green;
    padding-top: 200px;
    @top-center {
     vertical-align: top;
     content: element(header);
    }   
    @bottom-center {
     content: element(footer);
    }
   }     
   div.Page1Header {
    page: page1;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: running(header);
   }     
   div.Page1Footer {
    page: page1;
    position: running(footer);
   }        
   div.Page1Content {                    
    page: page1;
   }
      
   @page page2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    @top-center {
     vertical-align: top;
     content: element(header);
    }
    @bottom-center {
     content: element(footer);
    }
   }     
   div.Page2Header {
    page: page2;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: running(header);
   }     
   div.Page2Footer {
    page: page2;
    position: running(footer);
   }        
   div.Page2Content {                    
    page: page2;
   }
  </style>
</head>        
 <body>
    <apex:include pageName="testPage1" />
    <apex:include pageName="testPage2" />
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>```
````

Comment: One thing that could potentially be helpful is to know that Salesforce uses some version of [FlyingSaucer](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer) to render HTML as PDF. This library supports a limited set of CSS rules and even if your style definition was correct for a browser / printer, it might not be possible via FlyingSaucer. Something to check out, anyway.